# ASP.NET MVC Complex Model properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm creating a new ASP.NET MVC (with Entity Framework) project and I'm struggling a bit to understand what should I do when facing this "problem":

Lets say I have the **foo** model:

```
public class foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Book {get; set;}

    public int BookID {get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Theme> Themes {get; set;}

    /* Now what ?!? */
}
```

So let me try to explain:

- I learned that to simply the View-Controller process of getting a dropdownlist to get a select element and binding it with his "parent" model I had to have an "ID" field for the **Book ID** and a virtual property for the actual relation with the Book model. I really don't know if it's the "best" approach for start.
- Then I had to add a "list" of other model type to my **Foo** model. So now what should I do? In terms of View I was thinking creating a list of checkboxes with a scroll with do the trick but my main problem is still figure out how to handle the "model relation problem".

Thank you.

Comment: If you're not planning on subtyping your model, there's no point in marking properties `virtual`.

Comment: I was in the ideia that the "virtual" in this case had a special meaning related to the EF. No sure though.... I know virtual from C++ and I don't if you are confusing (maybe) ?

Comment: Oh, you didn't mention you were using EF. Yeah, it has an effect there.

Comment: My bad. I'll edit.

Comment: What is the question ? Sorry i do not understand

Comment: Tip: do not use Entity Framework entity/domain model classes as viewmodels. Instead have dedicated viewmodel classes for your views. The ViewModel should represent 2-way data between the View (and browser) and the controller. For 1-way data (such as DropDownList items) use `ViewData` or `ViewBag`.

Comment: I'm not using my model as a viewmodel. What I'm doing is creating my model and then scaffolding it to generate my controller and views.

Answer (score 0):

You need refer foo in Theme

```
public class foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Book {get; set;}

    public int BookID {get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Theme> Themes {get; set;}

}

public class Theme
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Foreignkey("fooID")]
    public virtual foo foo{get; set;}

    public int fooID {get; set; }

}
```

Comment: It's a many-to-many relation, so I don't think Theme refering Foo is going to do it.